# Session and APP Scope for COM objects

Tags: com, asp-classic, vbscript, windows-ce, atl

We are going to develop ASP pages for a WIN CE device. The web server running on the system is httpd. I have a few doubts on the scope of com objects

```
Does WinCE(httpd) ASP support Session and App Scope?  
Does page scope alone is supported in ASP in Wince?  
What should I do to introduce session and app Scope?  
Where can I get more information on this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Does WinCE(httpd) ASP support Session and App Scope?*

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms880937.aspx):

> Windows CE does not provide support
>   for the Session or Application objects
>   and does not send the Session-ID
>   cookie that is used on IIS. Therefore,
>   there is no automatic technique for
>   maintaining states between requests or
>   sessions.

About *creating COM objects in Wince ASP*, from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450214.aspx):

> To create a COM object on Windows
>   CE–based ASP, use the scripting
>   language support for creating COM
>   objects, instead of the
>   Server.CreateObject method, as you
>   would using IIS-based ASP.

Sample code from the same page:

```
<%
    dim newObject
    set newObject = CreateObject("class.name")
%>
```

*Where can I get more information on this?*

[MSDN - Web Server(HTTPD) Windows CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms899583.aspx)

Comment: Bear in mind the COM object must be compiled for CE.The one thing MSDN doesn't say is "if you intend to do anything useful with the built-in ASP server, you're going to end up both frustrated and disappointed"