# Create Page Scope Object in WinCE ASP

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, windows-ce

I have to create a page scope COM object in ASP for WIN CE device. The Win CE device supports only httpd server.

I tried to create the com object with the statement `Server.CreateObject` to give it page scope. But I am getting the following error

```
Parse error in script 
Microsoft VBScript runtime error: '800a01b6' 
Description: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'Server.CreateObject' 
In file: /Polycold_WebGUI/PolyCold_system_home.asp 
On line: 13
```

How can I correct this problems?
Can I give Page Scope for COM object in Win CE ASP?

**Result**
The method `GetUnitModelNumber` increments a member variable and returns the result. Initially the value is 0. Each time GetUnitModelNumber is executed the value will increment. As the default object life time is page scope, My expectation is that the second CreateObject call will return the object already created and the value will increment. But I am getting 0 when I executed the following piece of code. ***What is wrong with the following code?***

```
Dim objAd1,man
 Set objAd1 = CreateObject("PolyColdDeviceCmds.SystemCmds")
 man1 = objAd1.GetUnitModelNumber()
 Set objAd1 = CreateObject("PolyColdDeviceCmds.SystemCmds")
 man2 = objAd1.GetUnitModelNumber()
 Response.Write(man2)
 Response.Write("<script language='javascript'> alert("""&man2&""");</script>")
```

Comment: If you omit the second CreateObject call does it behave the way you expect?

Comment: "My expectation is that the second CreateObject call will return the object already created(...)" and why are you expecting that? If you ask for a new object with a call to CreateObject, you will get a new object...

Comment: @yms: How Can I say that it it Page Scope? Is there any problem with my understanding. Is it possible to use the object while reloading the page?

Comment: Could you please tell us what your ultimate goal is?

Comment: @yms: My aim is to create an object when a page is first loaded. Use the same object when user performs some operations on the page for eg: Clear Alarm, Execute Command Etc. I should be able to use the object even after the user refreshes the page

Comment: In order to do something like that you will need a Session Scope, which is not available in asp-wince

Comment: That was what ctacke was refering to when he said you would end up frustrated and dissapointed... Your only choice is to serialize your object in a file or a database and reload from there each time.This might be a bit slow though.

Comment: @yms: Then Page Scope means = I can access the object across different areas of the page. is that correct?.

Comment: @Maanu: ASP is stateless, so when you create the object in the page, the object is "live" for the entire page processing *for that load*.  Whne the page is loaded again, all states must be re-initialized.  Suine you don't have Session support, you'll have to implement something like it. A COM object would work where you pass in a key and an object, the key you'd maintain through a cookie, assuming that's supported in classic ASP on CE - I really don't know if it is or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How can I correct these problems?*

As I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6228561/session-and-app-scope-for-com-objects/6230956#6230956), you cannot use `Server.CreateObject` in asp-WinCE, you should use just `CreateObject` instead. Only `MapPath` and `URLEncode` are supported by the Server object in asp-WinCE. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa450214.aspx) in MSDN for details. From this page:

> The **Server object** provides access to
>   methods and properties on the server.
>   Most of these methods and properties
>   serve as utility functions. The
>   following table shows the supported
>   server methods.
>
> *Server method -  Windows CE
>   implementation*
>
>  ScriptTimeout:  Not
>   supported.
>  **CreateObject:   Not
>   supported.**
>  Execute:    Not
>   supported.
>  GetLastError:     Not
>   supported.
>  HTMLEncode:   Not
>   supported.
>  MapPath:  Fully
>   supported.
>  Transfer:     Not
>   supported.
>  URLEncode:    Fully
>   supported.

*Can I give Page Scope for COM object in Win CE ASP?*

Page Scope is the default behaviour for any COM object created within an asp page. See this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525036%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for details. From this page:

> An object that you create by using
>   Server.CreateObject or the HTML
>    tag on an ASP page exists for
>   the duration of that page.

This page talks about classic asp in Windows (desktop), not Windows CE. So for Windows CE just replace `Server.CreateObject` by `CreateObject` and you should get the same results.